# Show image in jsp from config.properties

Tags: java, image, jsp, controller

I need to load image from config.properties a show it in jsp page with cotroller. I need simple solution. How does it work?
Thank you

Edit:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
try {
    prop.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
    String path = prop.getProperty("filepath") + filename + ".jpg";

    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteimage = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write( image, "jpg", byteimage );
    byteimage.flush();
    byte[] imageInByte = byteimage.toByteArray();
    byteimage.close();

    model.addAttribute("image", Base64.getEncoder().encode(imageInByte));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried this but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You can store in your *.properties file image in BASE64 format. Get it in controller via `@Value private String image` annotation, than sand to your view. In view show accepted image: `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,HERE_BASE64_IMAGE/>`.

Comment: follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18975077/how-to-add-object-in-using-model-addattributes-in-spring-mvc) and try add your image data into **ModelMap** instead **Model**